Second directional derivative of convex conjugate
Let $f: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Define the conjugate
$$f^*(a) := \sup_{t \in [0, 1]} \{at - f(t)\}$$
and so $f^*$ is closed convex (even though $f$ is nonconvex). I would like to figure out sufficient conditions on $f$ such that $f^*$ has strictly positive directional second derivative at 0. To be more specific, for a function $g$ we define
$$g''(x; h) := \liminf_{\delta \downarrow 0} \frac{g(x+2\delta h) - 2g(x + \delta h) + g(x)}{\delta^2}$$
Since $f^*$ is convex, we know $(f^*)''(x; h) \geq 0$ everywhere. I would like to know about when $(f^*)''(0; 1) > 0$ (i.e. when the second directional derivative at 0 in the positive direction is nonzero).
For some intuition, when $f^*$ is differentiable then $\nabla f^*(0) = t_*$ is the unique argmin of $f$, i.e. $\{t_*\} = \operatorname{argmin}_{t \in [0, 1]}f(t)$. By convex duality, I know that if $f$ is convex and twice-differentiable with nonsingular Hessian then $\nabla^2 f^*(0) = (\nabla^2 f(t_*))^{-1}$ (there are some generalizations to non smooth $f$ that make use of a second-order subdifferential, such as in Theorem 4.7 here, but these are developed for convex $f$). Morally, second derivatives of $f^*$ at 0 ought to capture some kind of curvature of $f$ around $t_*$, but I am struggling to figure out the right kind of nondegeneracy to ensure that $(f^*)''(0; 1) > 0$. In the end, my goal is to classify measures on $C([0, 1])$ that give full mass to functions $f$ satisfying this condition. It would also be nice to generalize the $[0, 1]$ setting to general compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, but I first would like to understand this case well.
If anyone could offer any help, I would be very thankful. I am rather new to convex analysis, and I am having trouble extending my understanding beyond the cases when $f$ is convex or Hessians exist. Happy holidays to anyone reading this!

Why do you use "morally" in the apparent sense of "heuristically"?

Also, instead of argmax you should have argmin.

You are right, fixed to argmin. As for “morally”, i had a professor who uses it like that and it feels fun and elegant. Why not? :)

Also, the 2nd directional second derivative of $f^*$ at $0$ may not exist. So, I think your question should be edited accordingly. Do you want to replace $\lim_{\delta \downarrow 0}$ by $\liminf_{\delta \downarrow 0}$?

Have you tried to analyze this when $f$ is smooth? For an arbitrary convex function, the Hessian is a measure that can have a nonvanishing singular part. $f(x)=|x|$ is the basic example. I also suggest looking at Rockafellar's book Convex Analysis.

Thank you both for responding! If I am not mistaken, for $f$ twice-differentiable (and with a unique minimizer $t_* = (f^)'(0)$, but this will happen almost surely for my purposes) we get that $(f^)''(0) = 1/f''(t_)$, i.e. we would require that $f''$ doesn't vanish at its minimizer. Some functions (such as $f(x) = x^4$) fail this case, but at least it is testable. My hope is that for my directional second derivative criterion, it looks something like a nonzero directional second derivative of $f$ near $t_$...

@DeaneYang Regarding a weak Hessian of $f^$ evaluated at 0, I guess the condition would be that the measure $\mu := D^2(f^)$ should assign positive mass to positive neighborhoods of 0, such as $\mu([0, \epsilon)) > 0$? I am not sure how to make use of duality to derive a condition for $f$, though. I have not really seen results about duality for distributional Hessians in Rockafellar, do you know of any reference for this material particularly?

Do you have a response to the answer below?

$\newcommand\R{\Bbb R}\newcommand\bar\underline$You wrote:

but these are developed for convex $f$

Let us show that without loss of generality we may assume that $f$ is convex. More specifically, let us show that
$$f^*=g^*, \tag{1}\label{1}$$
where $g$ is the greatest convex minorant of $f$, defined by the formula
$$g(x):=\sup\{a(x)\colon a\in A,\ a\le f\}$$
for real $x$, where $A$ is the set of all affine functions on $\Bbb R$; here we assume that $f$ was extended to $\Bbb R$ by $\infty$.
Indeed, clearly $g\le f$ and hence
$$f^*(y)=\sup_{x\in\R}(xy-f(x))\le\sup_{x\in\R}(xy-g(x))=g^*(y)$$
for all $y\in\R$, so that $f^*\le g^*$.
To obtain the reverse inequality, take any real $y$ and consider the affine function $\R\ni x\mapsto a_y(x):=yx-f^*(y)$. Then for all real $x$ we have
$a_y(x)\le yx-(xy-f(x))=f(x)$ and hence $a_y(x)\le g(x)$, that is,
$yx-f^*(y)\le g(x)$, that is,
$f^*(y)\ge xy-g(x)$. So, $f^*(y)\ge\sup_{x\in\R}(xy-g(x))=g^*(y)$, for all real $y$. Thus, $f^*\ge g^*$, which completes the proof of \eqref{1}.
So, what was developed for the conjugates $f^*$ of convex functions $f$ is applicable to the conjugates of non-convex functions $f$.
